# Which GCP Log Explorer query will show success message of data loading to BigQuery by Dataflow Job so that log sink to pub/sub can be created

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-logging

I am running a Dataflow streaming job which reads data from pub/sub topic and performs streaming insert into BigQuery.

Once data loaded, I want to capture the success status from Log explorer to send acknowledgement back to another pub/sub topic.

What Log Explorer query can serve the purpose ?

I tried to run query below, but did not help.

```
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.datasetId="[REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_DATASET_ID]"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.projectId="REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
protoPayload.state="DONE"
```

Please help.

Thanking you,
Santanu

Comment: The path `protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.datasetId` looks like it's referring to a BigQuery LoadJob. If you're using streaming inserts rather than batch loads in your pipeline, then there is no concept of load jobs, which may explain why this query isn't providing useful output.

Comment: @JeffKlukas - possibly I am using wrong query, plz let me know what should be correct query in such case

Comment: Why do you not use a multi sink in the `Dataflow` job for good outputs, one to Bigquery and other to PubSub ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun - the requirement is to create single sink with BQ thru pub/sub and from BQ send ack to another pub/sub topic

Comment: Yes but you can directly do a multi sink in your Dataflow job, based on good outputs